# $A_1 \cup A_2$ is not a sigma Algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ und $A_1, A_2$ be two sigma Algebras over $X$ with $A_1\not \subseteq A_2$ and $A_2\not \subseteq A_1$. Show, that $A_1 \cup A_2$ cannot be a Sigma Algebra over $X$.
My Idea: Because $A_1\not \subseteq A_2$ and $A_2\not \subseteq A_1$, I find $y\in A_1$ with $y\not \in A_2$ and $z\in A_2$ with $z\not \in A_1$. Also $y^c\not\in A_2$ and $z^c\not\in A_1$. Now, I think I have to show that $y\cup z \not \in A_1 \cup A_2$.
Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We go on with your start: $y\in A_1-A_2$ and $z\in A_2-A_1$

If $A_1\cup A_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then WLOG we may assume that $y\cap z\in A_1$ and consequently that $y\cap z^c\in A_1$ and $y^c\cap z\in A_2$.

Also $y^c\cap z^c\in A_1$ or $y^c\cap z^c\in A_2$ but both options lead to a contradiction.

If e.g. $y^c\cap z^c\in A_1$ then $z^c\in A_1$ and consequently $z\in A_1$ contradicting that $z\in A_2-A_1$.

A similar contradiction arises on the other option. It leads to $y^c\in A_2$ and consequently $y\in A_2$ contradicting that $y\in A_1-A_2$.

Finally let me state that it is true for algebra's already.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked something.